# SQL Query Help (Advanced - for me!) 

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question about a SQL query I am trying to write.

I need to query data from a database. 
The database has, amongst others, these 3 fields:

Account_ID #, Date_Created, Time_Created

I need to write a query that tells me how many accounts were opened per hour.

I have written said query, but there are times that there were 0 accounts created, so these "hours" are not populated in the results.

For example:

> Volume ***Date*_**_Hour
>   435    12-Aug-12  03
>   213    12-Aug-12  04
>   125    12-Aug-12  06

As seen in the example above, hour 5 did not have any accounts opened.

Is there a way that the result can populate the hour but and display 0 accounts opened for this hour? 
Example of how I want my results to look like:

Volume ***Date***_Hour
435 12-Aug-12  03
213 12-Aug-12  04
0     12-Aug-12  05
125 12-Aug-12  06

Thanks!

Update: This is what I have so far

```
SELECT count(*) as num_apps, to_date(created_ts,'DD-Mon-RR') as app_date, to_char(created_ts,'HH24') as app_hour 
FROM accounts 
WHERE To_Date(created_ts,'DD-Mon-RR') >= To_Date('16-Aug-12','DD-Mon-RR') 
GROUP BY To_Date(created_ts,'DD-Mon-RR'), To_Char(created_ts,'HH24') 
ORDER BY app_date, app_hour
```

Comment: Have you tried looking into a Case statement? Reference: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php I could help you further if I could see your query that you have built already.

Comment: Hi! This is what I have so far: 
select count(*) as num_apps, to_date(created_ts,'DD-Mon-RR') as app_date, to_char(created_ts,'HH24') as app_hour from accounts Where To_Date(created_ts,'DD-Mon-RR') >= To_Date('16-Aug-12','DD-Mon-RR') Group By To_Date(created_ts,'DD-Mon-RR'), To_Char(created_ts,'HH24') order by app_date, app_hour

Comment: Sorry, I dont know how to format it well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the results you want, you will need to create a table (or use a query to generate a "temp" table) and then use a left join to your calculation query to get rows for every hour - even those with 0 volume.

For example, assume I have a table with app_date and app_hour fields.  Also assume that this table has a row for every day/hour you wish to report on.

The query would be:

```
SELECT NVL(c.num_apps,0) as num_apps, t.app_date, t.app_hour
    FROM time_table t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT count(*) as num_apps, to_date(created_ts,'DD-Mon-RR') as app_date, to_char(created_ts,'HH24') as app_hour 
    FROM accounts 
    WHERE To_Date(created_ts,'DD-Mon-RR') >= To_Date('16-Aug-12','DD-Mon-RR') 
    GROUP BY To_Date(created_ts,'DD-Mon-RR'), To_Char(created_ts,'HH24') 
    ORDER BY app_date, app_hour
    ) c ON (t.app_date = c.app_date AND t.app_hour = c.app_hour)
```

Comment: Looks awesome.  
I know there are ways to create tables localy on my machine, correct? I'll look into how to do those as I'm not allowed to create tables on the database.

Comment: Could you achieve it with an inline from?  i.e. SELECT 0 FROM dual UNION SELECT 1 FROM dual UNION SELECT 2 FROM dual etc...

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best solution is not to create some fancy temporary table but just use this construct:

```
select level
FROM Dual
CONNECT BY level <= 10
ORDER BY level;
```

This will give you (in ten rows):
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

For hours interval just little modification:

```
select 0 as num_apps, (To_Date('16-09-12','DD-MM-RR') + level / 24) as created_ts
FROM dual
CONNECT BY level <= (sysdate - To_Date('16-09-12','DD-MM-RR')) * 24 ;
```

And just for the fun of it adding solution for you(I didn't try syntax, so I'm sorry for any mistake, but the idea is clear):

```
 SELECT SUM(num_apps) as num_apps, to_date(created_ts,'DD-Mon-RR') as app_date, to_char(created_ts,'HH24') as app_hour 
FROM(
  SELECT count(*) as num_apps, created_ts
  FROM accounts 
  WHERE To_Date(created_ts,'DD-Mon-RR') >= To_Date('16-09-12','DD-MM-RR') 
UNION ALL
  select 0 as num_apps, (To_Date('16-09-12','DD-MM-RR') + level / 24) as created_ts
  FROM dual
  CONNECT BY level <= (sysdate - To_Date('16-09-12','DD-MM-RR')) * 24 ;  
)
GROUP BY To_Date(created_ts,'DD-Mon-RR'), To_Char(created_ts,'HH24') 
ORDER BY app_date, app_hour
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a CASE statement in the SELECT to force the value you want.

Comment: Please clarify as I cannot see how this will work.  The query is only looking at the accounts table.  If there are zero accounts for that hour, how will you get the database to return a row that doesn't exist by using a CASE statement?

Answer (score 0):

It can be useful to have a "sequence table" kicking around, for all sorts of reasons, something that looks like this:

```
create table dbo.sequence
(
  id int not null primary key clustered ,  
)
```

Load it up with million or so rows, covering positive and negative values.

Then, given a table that looks like this

```
create table dbo.SomeTable
(
  account_id   int  not null primary key clustered ,
  date_created date not null ,
  time_created time not null ,
)
```

Your query is then as simple as (in SQL Server):

```
select year_created  = years.id  ,
       month_created = months.id ,
       day_created   = days.id   ,
       hour_created  = hours.id  ,
       volume        = t.volume
from       ( select * ,
                    is_leap_year = case
                                   when id % 400 = 0 then 1
                                   when id % 100 = 0 then 0
                                   when id %   4 = 0 then 1
                                   else                   0
                                   end
             from dbo.sequence
             where id between 1980 and year(current_timestamp)
           ) years
cross join ( select *
             from dbo.sequence
             where id between 1 and 12
           ) months
left  join ( select *
             from dbo.sequence
             where id between 1 and 31
           ) days on days.id <= case months.id
                                when  2 then 28 + years.is_leap_year
                                when  4 then 30
                                when  6 then 30
                                when  9 then 30
                                when 11 then 30
                                else         31
                                end
cross join ( select *
             from dbo.sequence
             where id between 0 and 23
           ) hours
left join ( select date_created ,
                   hour_created = datepart(hour,time_created ) ,
                   volume = count(*)
            from dbo.SomeTable
            group by date_created ,
                     datepart(hour,time_created)
          ) t on datepart( year  , t.date_created ) = years.id
             and datepart( month , t.date_created ) = months.id
             and datepart( day   , t.date_created ) = days.id
             and t.hour_created                     = hours.id
order by 1,2,3,4
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me if `created_ts` is a datetime or a varchar. If it's a datetime, you shouldn't use `to_date`; if it's a varchar, you shouldn't use `to_char`.

Assuming it's a datetime, and borrowing @jakub.petr's `FROM Dual CONNECT BY level` trick, I suggest:

```
SELECT count(*) as num_apps, to_char(created_ts,'DD-Mon-RR') as app_date, to_char(created_ts,'HH24') as app_hour 
FROM (select level-1 as hour FROM Dual CONNECT BY level <= 24) h 
  LEFT JOIN accounts a on h.hour = to_number(to_char(a.created_ts,'HH24'))
WHERE created_ts >= To_Date('16-Aug-12','DD-Mon-RR') 
GROUP BY trunc(created_ts), h.hour 
ORDER BY app_date, app_hour
```